# Unique with subsequent element only

Tags: r

My input is a vector like this

```
v = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,4,1,1)
```

`unique(v) == c(1,2,3,4,5)`

instead, I need to check and operate uniqueness only on pairs of subsequent element:

`.f(v) == c(1,2,3,4,5,4,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rle` from `base R` and extract the 'values'

```
rle(v)$values
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 4 1
```

`unique` gets the `unique` values from the whole dataset, whereas `rle` returns a `list` of 'values' and its `lengths` for each adjacent unique value

---

Or another option is to do a comparison with the current and adjacent value and apply `duplicated` to subset the vector

```
v[!duplicated(cumsum(c(TRUE, v[-1] != v[-length(v)])))]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
v[v != dplyr::lag(v, default = Inf)]

#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 4 1
```